# Generate object coordinates in relation to neighbours

Tags: java, algorithm, object, data-structures, coordinates

I am making a game in which i have randomly spawned objects. I also have a table that has the data of which objects are close to one another, say within a range of `200px` - lets call them neighbors. What i want is to generate and assign coordinates to all the available objects so that this relationship is reflected. I want to view the structure of how they are. 
I have made a greedy algorithm. Which works very slowly. and gets stuck sometimes. Does anyone have a better approach to this? - the coordinates can be assigned dynamically through trial and error no problem.
Below is the current code classes.

```
    /**
     * biggest problem
     * */
    public void assignInitialCoords( MyObject[] objects )
    {
        objects[0].setxCoor(rand.nextInt(1000));
        objects[0].setyCoor(rand.nextInt(1000));

        for(int i=0; i<objects.length; i++ )
        {
            ArrayList<MyObject> neighs = objects[i].getNeighbours();
            System.out.println("Assigning " + objects[i].getId() + "'s coors");
            setNonNeighborCoords(objects, i);
            setNeighborCoordinates(objects, i, neighs);
            System.out.println(objects[i].getId() + "(" + objects[i].getxCoor() + ", " + objects[i].getyCoor() + ")\n");
        }
    }
```

The classes

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class MyObject
{
    public ArrayList<MyObject> neighbours;
    public ArrayList<MyObject> nonNeighbours;
    public double fov = 360;
    public double sRange = 100, xCoor, yCoor;
    boolean isClustered = false;
    public String id;
    //Cluster[] clusters;


    public MyObject()
    {
        neighbours = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
        nonNeighbours = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
    }

    /**
     * Find neighbours for this Object given a relations table
     * example: if a MyObject has id A, and neighbor is B, then the key can be either: A_B or B_A
     * Both represent the same relation, so we only need to check it once
     * */
    public void findNeighbours(HashMap<String, Integer> table, MyObject[] objects)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < objects.length; i++)
        {
            String key1 = getId() + "_" + objects[i].getId(), key2 = objects[i].getId() +"_" + getId(), key="";
            if(table.get(key1) != null) 
            {
                key = key1;
                if(table.get(key) <= getsRange())
                    getNeighbours().add(objects[i]);
            }
            if(table.get(key2) != null) 
            {
                key = key2;
                if(table.get(key) <= getsRange())
                    getNeighbours().add(objects[i]);
            }   
        }
    }

    /**
     * Check whether a given Object is the neighbour ArrayList of this object
     * */
    public boolean isInNeighbours( MyObject n )
    {
        if(neighbours.equals(null)) { return false; }
        for(int i=0; i<getNeighbours().size(); i++)
            if(getNeighbours().get(i).getId().equals(n.getId())) { return true; }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Check whether a given Object is the noneighbour ArrayList of this object
     * */
    public boolean isInNonNeighbours( MyObject n )
    {
        if(nonNeighbours.equals(null)) { return false; }
        for(int i=0; i<getNonNeighbours().size(); i++)
            if(getNonNeighbours().get(i).getId().equals(n.getId())) { return true; }
        return false;
    }


    /**
     * Check if given MyObject Can be a neighbour to this Object - for rand coord generation
     * */
    public boolean canBeANeighbour(MyObject n)
    {
        return distanceTo(n) <= sRange;
    }

    // return Euclidean distance between this and p 
   public double distanceTo(MyObject p) {
      double dx = this.xCoor - p.xCoor;
      double dy = this.yCoor - p.yCoor;
      return Math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);
   }

    //Setters And Getters
    public ArrayList<MyObject> getNeighbours(){ return neighbours; }

    public void setNeighbours(ArrayList<MyObject> neighbours)
    {
        this.neighbours = neighbours;
    }
    public double getFov()
    {
        return fov;
    }
    public void setFov(double fov)
    {
        this.fov = fov;
    }
    public double getsRange()
    {
        return sRange;
    }
    public void setsRange(double sRange)
    {
        this.sRange = sRange;
    }
    public double getxCoor()
    {
        return xCoor;
    }
    public void setxCoor(double xCoor)
    {
        this.xCoor = xCoor;
    }
    public double getyCoor()
    {
        return yCoor;
    }
    public void setyCoor(double yCoor)
    {
        this.yCoor = yCoor;
    }
    public boolean isClustered()
    {
        return isClustered;
    }
    public void setClustered(boolean isClustered)
    {
        this.isClustered = isClustered;
    }
    public String getId()
    {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public ArrayList<MyObject> getNonNeighbours()
    {
        return nonNeighbours;
    }

    public void setNonNeighbours(ArrayList<MyObject> nonNeighbours)
    {
        this.nonNeighbours = nonNeighbours;
    }
}
```

//The sample test:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Random;

public class SampleField
{
    Random rand = new Random();
    public int range = 100;
    HashMap<String, Integer> table = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    String[] nodeIds = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"};
    public MyObject[] objects = new MyObject[nodeIds.length];

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SampleField test = new SampleField();
        for(MyObject n: test.objects)
        {
            n.findNeighbours(test.table, test.objects);
        }
        test.populateNonNeighbours(test.objects);
        System.out.println(test.table);
        test.printRelationsTable(  test.objects );
        test.assignInitialCoords(test.objects);
        System.out.println(test.table);
        test.printRelationsTable(  test.objects );
    }

    public SampleField()
    {
        initialiseNodes();
        generateTestTable(objects);
    }

    /**
     * biggest problem
     * */
    public void assignInitialCoords( MyObject[] objects )
    {
        objects[0].setxCoor(rand.nextInt(1000));
        objects[0].setyCoor(rand.nextInt(1000));

        for(int i=0; i<objects.length; i++ )
        {
            ArrayList<MyObject> neighs = objects[i].getNeighbours();
            System.out.println("Assigning " + objects[i].getId() + "'s coors");
            setNonNeighborCoords(objects, i);
            setNeighborCoordinates(objects, i, neighs);
            System.out.println(objects[i].getId() + "(" + objects[i].getxCoor() + ", " + objects[i].getyCoor() + ")\n");
        }
    }

    /**
     * if this object has neighbours, try to set their coordinates so that they do not conflict
     * 
     * @param objects
     * @param i
     * @param neighs
     */
    private void setNeighborCoordinates(MyObject[] objects, int i, ArrayList<MyObject> neighs)
    {
        //it should have at least one neighbour
        if(neighs != null )
            for( int j=0; j<neighs.size(); j++ )
            {
                //Initial assignment to the first neighbor
                neighs.get(j).setxCoor(rand.nextInt() + objects[i].getsRange() );
                neighs.get(j).setyCoor(rand.nextInt() + objects[i].getsRange() );
                //If not a neighbor keep generating coordinates until it keeps being a neighbor.
                while( !objects[i].canBeANeighbour(neighs.get(j))  )
                {
                    //go deeper? - later
                    neighs.get(j).setxCoor(rand.nextInt(1000) - shootRange() - 5 );
                    neighs.get(j).setyCoor(rand.nextInt(1000) - shootRange() - 5 );
                }                               
            }
    }

    /**
     * try to set the coordinates of each object here
     * @param objects
     * @param i
     */
    private void setNonNeighborCoords(MyObject[] objects, int i)
    {
        for(MyObject n : objects[i].getNonNeighbours())
        {
            n.setxCoor(rand.nextInt() + shootRange() - 5);
            n.setyCoor(rand.nextInt() + shootRange() - 5);
                //Make sure non neighbors remain non neighbors
                while(objects[i].canBeANeighbour(n))
                {
                    n.setxCoor(rand.nextInt() + shootRange() - 5 );
                    n.setyCoor(rand.nextInt() + shootRange() - 5 );
                }

        }
    }

    /* populate nonNeighbours */
    public void populateNonNeighbours(MyObject[] objects)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<objects.length; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j<objects.length; j++ )
            {
                if( (objects[i].getId() != objects[j].getId()) && !objects[i].isInNeighbours(objects[j]) )
                {
                    objects[i].getNonNeighbours().add(objects[j]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    /* Show each object and its neighbors/nonneighbors - just for output */
    public void printRelationsTable( MyObject[] objects )
    {
        for(int i=0; i<objects.length; i++ )
        {
            System.out.print("MyObject " + objects[i].getId() + "'s neighbours: ");
            for(int j=0; j<objects[i].getNeighbours().size(); j++)
            {
                System.out.print(objects[i].getNeighbours().get(j).getId() + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();

            System.out.print("\t\t" +objects[i].getId()+ "' : ");
            for(int j=0; j<objects[i].getNonNeighbours().size(); j++)
            {
                System.out.print(objects[i].getNonNeighbours().get(j).getId() + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
    /* Initialise Objects here - give basic information */
    public void initialiseNodes()
    {
        for(int i=0; i<nodeIds.length; i++)
        {
            MyObject n = new MyObject();
            n.setId(nodeIds[i]);
            n.setsRange(shootRange());
            objects[i] = n;
        }
    }

    /* Generate a list of neighbors for testing */
    public void generateTestTable(MyObject[] objects)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<objects.length; i++)
        {   
            /* Get two objects' ids and make them neighbors - ids must be unique */
            String firstId = objects[rand.nextInt(objects.length)].getId();
            String secondId = objects[rand.nextInt(objects.length)].getId();
            while( firstId.equals(secondId) || table.containsKey(firstId + "_" + secondId) || table.containsKey(secondId + "_" + firstId) )
            {
                firstId = objects[rand.nextInt(objects.length)].getId();
                secondId = objects[rand.nextInt(objects.length)].getId();
            }
            table.put(firstId + "_" + secondId, shootRange());
        }
    }

    /* Range within which they are neighbors */
    public int shootRange()
    {
        return range;
    }

    public void setRange(int range)
    {
        this.range = range;
    }   
}
```

Comment: If you want us to give you an advice for improving your algorithms, put here your classes with explanations. Just now the code is unreadible.

Comment: @Gangnus I have added the classes as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only compare distances (and if you are talking about neighbours, it seems so), then you don't need to count them at all. Instead of

```
range = sqrt(sqr(a.x-b.x)+sqr(a.y-b.y))
if (range >d)...
```

use

```
sqrange(a,b) = sqr(a.x-b.x)+sqr(a.y-b.y)
if (range> d_sqr) ...
```

That means, you don't use ranges, but their squares. That quickens the comparisons about 50 times (for double). So, you can use much more easy structures.

Comment: yes am talking about neighbours, but whilst assigning them coordinates, I dont want an object that wasnt a neighbor to given objects become a neighbor to them in the process. alright. I will post the whole classes soon.

Comment: ok, I tried this, but still no apparent change in performance.

Comment: You have stopped to use sqrt and noticed no change? Sorry, that is impossible. Or you have really great problems elsewhere.

Comment: Oh! You are creating strings in the inner cycle! That operations with IDs are senseless and terribly ineffective.

Comment: We can understand the problems of your code if it is 90% sensible and we have to find some separate problems in otherway understandable code. It is not so here. Sorry, your code is total mishmash. What are you doing? Explain the task, divide it in subtasks, define them. Leave these definitions in code.

Comment: mhm, thats true. I just wrote this off in one go. Am gona edit it then update it.

Comment: @gordon And don't forget to do that not for us only, but for yourself, too. It is the correct way of code writing. The code should be readable

Comment: @Gangus I have editted it in its original form - i hope its a bit more understandable now. I completely agree to the format and style suggestions. I just didnt expect this to be not as straight forward as I had assumed it would be :).